# Наследование JS. Скажите, плиз, почему возвращает undefined, а не строку

Tags: javascript

```js
class Animal {
  /** Ваш код */
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  say() {
    return `${this.name} says`;
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  /** Ваш код */
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  static get pharse() {
    return 'meow';
  }

  say() {
    return `${super.say()} ${Cat.pharse}`;
  }
}
let cat = new Cat("Vasya");
console.log(cat.pharse); //undefined, а нужна строка
```

Answer (score 4):

Статическое свойство `pharse` (`phrаse`?) принадлежит определению класса `Cat`, а не объекту `cat`.

```js
class Animal {
  /** Ваш код */
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  say() {
    return `${this.name} says`;
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  /** Ваш код */
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  static get pharse() {
    return 'meow';
  }

  say() {
    return `${super.say()} ${Cat.pharse}`;
  }
}
let cat = new Cat("Vasya");
console.log(Cat.pharse);
console.log(cat.say());
```

> А как тогда определить метод, чтобы cat.pharse вывел строку,

```js
class Animal {
  /** Ваш код */
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  say() {
    return `${this.name} says`;
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  /** Ваш код */
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  get pharse() { // это не метод, а свойство
    return 'meow';
  }

  say() {
    return `${super.say()} ${this.pharse}`;
  }
}
let cat = new Cat("Vasya");
console.log(cat.pharse);
console.log(cat.say());
```

Comment: А как тогда определить метод, чтобы cat.pharse вывел строку, у меня из-за этого тесты не проходят.