# Почему перезагружается страница с таким кодом, а если добавить пару строк (указанную ниже) в консоль - не перезагружает?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, плиз, вот у меня есть пару файлов, я пытаюсь вывести полученные значения из формы, и вот в чем вопрос, если вот эти две строки из main.js:

```
let formHandler = new App.FormHandler('[data-coffee-order="form"]');
formHandler.addSubmitHandler(myTruck.createOrder.bind(myTruck));
```

я добавляю в консоли, то работает (выводит и не перегружает страницу), если в консоли это не добавлять, хотя в файле тоже самое - страница перегружается каждый раз при отправке формы и ничего не выводит.
truck.js

```
(function (window) {
    'use strict';
    let App = window.App || {};
    let $ = window.jQuery;
    function FormHandler(selector) {
        this.$formElement = $(selector);
    }
    FormHandler.prototype.addSubmitHandler = function (fn) {
            console.log('Setting submit handler for form');
            this.$formElement.on('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                let data = {};
                $(this).serializeArray().forEach(function (item) {
                    data[item.name] = item.value;
                    console.log(`${item.name} is ${item.value}`);
                });
                console.log(data);
                fn(data);
                this.reset();
                this.elements[0].focus();
            });
    };
    App.FormHandler = FormHandler;
    window.App  = App;
})(window)
```

formhandler.js

```
(function (window) {
    'use strict';
    let App = window.App || {};
    let $ = window.jQuery;
    function FormHandler(selector) {
        this.$formElement = $(selector);
    }
    FormHandler.prototype.addSubmitHandler = function (fn) {
            console.log('Setting submit handler for form');
            this.$formElement.on('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                let data = {};
                $(this).serializeArray().forEach(function (item) {
                    data[item.name] = item.value;
                    console.log(`${item.name} is ${item.value}`);
                });
                console.log(data);
                fn(data);
                this.reset();
                this.elements[0].focus();
            });
    };
    App.FormHandler = FormHandler;
    window.App  = App;
})(window)
```

main.js

```
(function(window){
    'use strict';
    let App = window.App;
    let Truck = App.Truck;
    let DataStore = App.DataStore;
    let myTruck = new Truck('ncc-1701', new DataStore());
    window.myTruck = myTruck;
    let formHandler = new App.FormHandler('[data-coffee-order="form"]');
    formHandler.addSubmitHandler(myTruck.createOrder.bind(myTruck));
    console.log(formHandler);
})(window)
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в момент вызова `(function(window){...}(window)` в странице еще нет элемента `'[data-coffee-order="form"]'`.

---

Да, и Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать?

[Наследование JS. Скажите, плиз, почему возвращает undefined, а не строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944521/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-js-%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-undefined-%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: Спасибо, поняла ошибку.